Git Fetch Error in Android Studio with SSH Config for Multiple Accounts in Flutter project
I have two GitHub accounts:

Personal: myusername
Work: myusername-sh

My work account (myusername-sh) has access to this repository: my-company-name/cherubi
my-company-name is the company I work for.
Here's my SSH config file:
# Primary account
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_myusername

# SH account
Host github.com-sh
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_myusername_sh

I can successfully clone the repository using this command in the terminal:
git clone git@github.com-sh:my-company-name/cherubi.git

When I run git remote -v, it shows:
❯ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com-sh:my-company-name/cherubi.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com-sh:my-company-name/cherubi.git (push)

Using my own terminal, I can successfully perform git fetch and git pull.
However, when I use Android Studio and I click on "Get dependencies" for my flutter project (as shown in image),

Then, I encounter this error:
Git error. Command: git fetch
stdout: 
stderr: ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
exit code: 128

What I've Tried:

Verified that my SSH keys are correctly configured and that I have access rights.

Additional Information:

Operating System: Ubuntu 24
Android Studio Version: Android Studio Jellyfish | 2023.3.1 Patch 1

How can I resolve this issue so that Android Studio can correctly fetch from the remote repository using my work account's SSH key?
